# Select certificate based on Host header in Kestrel

Tags: .net-core, kestrel-http-server

I am trying to select the appropriate SSL certificate to use in a self hosted Kestrel server. The following code works fine for a DNS entry, but not for either an IP address or when the Host, or X-Forwarded-For headers are populated.

```
options.Listen(IPAddress.Any, port, listenOptions => listenOptions.UseHttps(httpsOptions =>
             {
                
                 httpsOptions.ServerCertificateSelector = (connectionContext, name) =>
                     {
                         ...logic to find cert...
                     };
             }
```

The `name` parameter is always empty with an IP, and I can't see how to find it from the connectionContext.  It also appears to be too early process for the HTTPContext to be available

Comment: Hi Owen, you can't select a certificate based on a HTTP header, as you can't send HTTP until the TLS connection has been negotiated (which requires selecting a certificate). TLS does have an extension called server name indication (SNI) which allows a compatible client to tell the server what host name it is connecting with so that the server can select an appropriate certificate and Kestrel apparently does support it. Check that your client supports SNI. You don't mention in your question what client you are using to connect.

Comment: Hi @DanL, that's mostly what I had come to realize.  I'll have to dig more into the SNI implementation to see if I can piggy back off of that.
In this case, my client is just postman

Comment: The SNI support is showed with examples in Microsoft's article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-5.0#listenoptionsusehttps and what you observed should be by design as SNI only matches certificates with Host header of incoming requests, not X-Forwarded-For nor IP addresses.